# JavaScript heap out of memory when running nodejs app inside ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I cloned an expressjs api inside an Ubuntu 20.x server.

I try to run the following script: `tsc && node build/app.js`, but after a few seconds I get the following error:

> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [37431:0x4ba77f0]    23371 ms: Scavenge 482.9 (492.8) -> 482.5 (493.0)
> MB, 6.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.233, current mu = 0.195) allocation
> failure
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation
> failed - JavaScript heap out of memory 1: 0xb09980 node::Abort()
> [node] 2: 0xa1c235 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
> 3: 0xcf77be v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [node] 4: 0xcf7b37
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [node] 5: 0xeaf3d5  [node] 6: 0xeafeb6  [node] 7:
> 0xebe3de  [node] 8: 0xebee20
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node] 9:
> 0xec1d15 v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [node] 10: 0xe4f3b7
> v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [node] 11: 0x11fb775
> v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, unsigned long*,
> v8::internal::Isolate*) [node] 12: 0x15f0a99  [node] Aborted (core
> dumped)

I have followed posts that say to increase the heap size which I did all the way up to 8GB by adding it to my node script `node --max-old-space-size-8192 build/app.js`, but that has not helped.

I am working with Node version 16.14.0 in Ubuntu 20.x server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that an AWS t2micro is too small to run a Nodejs application, but a t2small should do the trick.